# C# convert string to entity

Tags: c#

I have a problem with converting string to entity of type OneWeighing.

I got this piece of code:

```
foreach (OneWeighing oneWeighing in _weighing)
{                    
    _oneWeighing.Add(oneWeighing.ScaleShortcut + " / " + oneWeighing.WeighingTime);                
}
```

Problem is in this particular line:

```
_oneWeighing.Add(oneWeighing.ScaleShortcut + " / " + oneWeighing.WeighingTime);
```

> Error: Cannot convert from string to Entities.WeighingSystem.TruckWeighing.OneWeighing.

Class:

```
   public OneWeighing();

    public bool CanBeCancelled { get; set; }
    public long IDWeighingDetail { get; set; }
    public long IDWeighingRecord { get; set; }
    public bool isCancelled { get; set; }
    public string ScaleShortcut { get; set; }
    public long WeighingRecordAlibi { get; set; }
    public DateTime WeighingTime { get; set; }
    public string WeighingType { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks :)

Comment: You have to assign that string to one of `oneWeighing`'s properties, or to one of a new instance of `OneWeighing`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Can you please give me example how? Thanks

Comment: How do you want to create an instance of `OneWeighing` from a string? We can´t know how this class looks like, it´s impossible for us to guess what you want to achieve.

Comment: can you please post the `OneWeighing` class structure? what is the value that you are calculating with `oneWeighing.ScaleShortcut + " / " + oneWeighing.WeighingTime` ? is there a corresponding property in the `OneWeighing` class where it can be assigned to?

Comment: Well class looks like this:

Comment: public OneWeighing();

        public bool CanBeCancelled { get; set; }
        public long IDWeighingDetail { get; set; }
        public long IDWeighingRecord { get; set; }
        public bool isCancelled { get; set; }
        public string ScaleShortcut { get; set; }
        public long WeighingRecordAlibi { get; set; }
        public DateTime WeighingTime { get; set; }
        public string WeighingType { get; set; }
        public float Weight { get; set; }

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding code as comment. It´s very hard to read this.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Edited.

Comment: And how does the string you provide to `Add` relate to that class? Is there a property that matches that string?

Comment: Some wild guessing `_oneWeighing.Add(oneWeighing)`?

Comment: now you confused me even more :) what kind of string do you expect? `somethingScaleShortcut / 20.12.2017 10:12:22` ??

Comment: @oliver If i add only oneweighing, in combobox i dont have proper string, i have in combobox Entities.WeighingSystem.OneWeighing, not the correct text

Comment: @MongZhu Scale is weigh type and date yes, this is the output

Comment: so it souns like a X-Y Problem. Are you trying to achieve a propper output in the ComboBox of each `OneWeighing` ? If so, then the solution would be to `override` the `ToString` method in your class and return this string

Comment: @Mong Zhu yes, that is what i trying to archieve

Answer (score 0):

You primary error comes from the point that you have a `List` that contains objects of type `OneWeighing` and you are trying to insert a `string` into it.

The simplest solution for you here would be simply to make a `List<string> _oneWeighing` that contains the crucial information from your objects as strings! This can be shoved into the `ComboBox`. Then your code will work.

But it seems for me that this is a X-Y Problem. (You should refactor your question as to reflect the correct aim.)

Ok, since you actually are trying to display the `OneWeighing` objects correctly in your `ComboBox` you need to override the `ToString` method in your `OneWeighing` class. This will be called to write the desired information into your combobox:

```
public class OneWeighing
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this..ScaleShortcut + " / " + this.WeighingTime;
    }    
}
```

Your problem that you get only `Entities.WeighingSystem.OneWeighing` in the `ComboBox` displayed arises because the inherited `ToString` method is called to display information about the object. The default method only displays the namespace and class name. This is why you get this output

Comment: Another solution would be to configure the combo box to show the desired child property value. E.g. in winforms you would set the [`DisplayMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) property.

Comment: @Oliver good point! Let's see how OP responds. May be he simply takes the string list approach and will not care about twiggling with the controls. But you are correct

Comment: Thanks for tips :) I will make it answered if it will work :)

Comment: @DanielCapek you are welcome, good luck. May be you should post the code which inserts the elements into the `ComboBox`